# Joomla zipping everything

Tags: php, joomla, path, joomla2.5

**Joomla version = 2.5.6**

**Server = Wamp Server**

**PHP = 5.3.8**

I finally figured out how to zip and array of files using the following code:

```
$filesArray = array();
$archivename = JPATH_SITE.'/'.'modules'.'/'.'mod_module_gen'.'/'.'package'.'/'.$new_folder_name.'/'.$new_folder_name.'.zip';
$excludes = array('.svn', '.zip','.DS_Store','__MACOSX','CVS');
$files = JFolder::files(JPATH_SITE.'/'.'modules'.'/'.'mod_module_gen'.'/'.'package'.'/'.$new_folder_name, null, true, true, $excludes);

foreach($files as $file)
{
    $data = JFile::read($file);
    $filesArray[] = array('name' => $file, 'data' => $data);
}

$zip =& JArchive::getAdapter('zip');
$zip->create($archivename, $filesArray);
```

However if doesnt just zip the files up in the folder that was created, It zips all the folders leading the the file array.

```
/wamp/www/joomjunk/modules/mod_module_gen/package/$new_folder_name/files
```

`$new_folder_name` = a user define name

It should only zip as shown below:

```
$new_folder_name/files
```

Is there something in the code that I have done wrong or something missing that is causing it to also zip all the previous folder? Any help would really appreciated. Regards

Comment: maybe try using relative path names would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use absolute path names like

```
JPATH_SITE.'/'.'modules'.'/'.'mod_module_gen'.'/'.'package'.'/'.$new_folder_name
```

you will get a archive with a folder structure which you provided to it.

Short example from the command line:

```
thomas@thinky ~ % tar -cf bar.tar image.jpg
thomas@thinky ~ % tar -cf foo.tar /home/thomas/image.jpg
```

Notice the folder structure in the archives:

```
thomas@thinky ~ % tar -tvf bar.tar
-rw-rw-r-- thomas/thomas 1922254 2012-04-23 20:02 image.jpg
thomas@thinky ~ % tar -tvf foo.tar
-rw-rw-r-- thomas/thomas 1922254 2012-04-23 20:02 home/thomas/image.jpg
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Thomas , how would I change the path from absolute to relative?

Comment: I answered this already look what I did to remove the `home/thomas/` in the archive. Maybe debug your application and look what is in `JPATH_SITE` and figure out in which directory your script is running. then build your path relative to the directory you want to zip. In the end the path may look similar to this: `../modules/mod_module_gen/package/'. $new_folder_name`.

Comment: I realised you answered it but was just a little confused with the commands. thanks for the help ;)